# Jquery changing the value of a drop-down using its value, not the text

Tags: javascript, jquery

I'm having difficulty changing the calue of a dropdown menu using jquery.

```
<div class="input-box">
    <select name="options[4]" id="select_4">
    <option value="">-- Please Select --</option>
    <option value="24">Not Sure - Send Me Some Samples First </option>
    <option value="13">1 Jet Black </option>
    <option value="14">Blondette 4/27 </option>
    <option value="15">Boho Blonde 613/12 </option>
    <option value="16">Caramel 6 </option>
    <option value="17">Cherry 530 </option>
    <option value="18">Dirty Blonde 612/12 </option>
    <option value="19">Ebony Black 1b </option>
    <option value="20">Hot Toffee 4 </option>
    <option value="21">LA Blond 24/613 </option>
    <option value="22">Malibu Blonde 60/613 </option>
    <option value="23">Raven 2 </option></select>
</div>
```

I can't understand why this won't work

```
function changeIt(theId) {
    $j('.input-box:eq(0)').val(theId);
}

changeIt(22);
```

Answer (score 3, accepted):

Well, you are not selecting the `select` element:

```
$j('.input-box:eq(0) select').val(theId);
```

`'.input-box:eq(0)'` only selects the div. And the `val()` method has no effect on divs.

[**DEMO**](http://jsfiddle.net/fkling/b2gf5/)

Comment: $j('.input-box:eq(0) select:selected').val(theId);

Comment: @Grant unwin: `:selected` is unnecessary. It only works for `option` elements: http://api.jquery.com/selected-selector/

Comment: +1 for your awesomeness, and my lameness :) And happy new year!

Comment: @karim79: Thanks :)(although I don't feel so awesome :D ;)) Happy new year to you too!

Comment: @Felix - And I feel worse, apparently I got into several fights (with my friends!). I woke up today with plasters all over my left arm, and what feels like a broken collar bone :)

Answer (score 1):

Try:

```
$j('.input-box:first select > option[value=' + theId + ']').attr('selected', 'selected');
```

Comment: I needed to be able to select the drop down using the containing div, because the option's id changes from page to page. So I didnt try this option.

Comment: Ah, edited. Felix's way is more concise (as you have probably noticed :)

Answer (score 0):

I figured it out. This loops through the first SELECT contained in the div with '.input-box' class. Pulling out the ID and the text.

```
$j('.input-box:eq(0) option').each(function() {

    theText=$j(this).text();
    itsId = $j(this).val();      

});
```

I used this to pull out all the values and generate buttons depending on the drop-downs current options. Then i used the folloqing function (onClick) to change the selected value of the drop-down.

```
function changeOption(theId) {
    //alert("Change to value number:"+theId);
    $j('.input-box select').val(theId); 
}
```